# How can I access the result of a SQL request in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

How can I access the result of a SQL request in JavaScript and store it in a variable?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM account where username='Mashiro';

+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|        9 |
+----------+
```

My code:

```js
    con.connect(function(err) {
        if (err)throw err;
            var sql = ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM account where username=?");
            con.query(sql,[username],function (err, result){
        if (err)throw err;
            console.log(result);

            var x = ???????????

            return result;
        })
    })
}
```

I'd like set the x variable to '9' like in the following:

```
console.log(x);    >>> 9
```

Comment: With the information provided nobody can answer. Which library are you using?

Comment: Try with the following sql-query:
SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM account where username=?"

And then access with result[0].count.
SQL Always returns an array, so you have to access with the index.
count is the property you set with as

Answer (score 0):

Select With a Filter
When selecting records from a table, you can filter the selection by using the "WHERE" statement:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "yourusername",
  password: "yourpassword",
  database: "mydb"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  con.query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customers WHERE username = ?", [$username], function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

More examples : https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_where.asp

More examples with prepare statements and more : https://evertpot.com/executing-a-mysql-query-in-nodejs/

Answer (score 0):

Like this i think it should work:

```
con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err)throw err;
        var sql = ("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM account where username=?");
        con.query(sql,[username],function (err, result){
    if (err)throw err;
        console.log(result[0].count);

        var x = result[0].count;

        return result;
    })
})
```

}